# Retrieve a table that contain the same fields in a specific column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of Users that contain this columns: l_code, l_name, year_of_birth.
I need to return a table that contain all the pairs of users (different) that have the same year of birth.
The new table will contain: user1, user2, year_of_birth. How can i implement that with sql query?

Comment: is `l_code` unique?

Comment: yes, l_code is unique

Comment: Creating a column for every user in same year in result doesn't sound like a good idea

Comment: example: Obama Trump 1952

Comment: What if there is a another user in same year `1952`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self join will do:

```
select t1.l_code, t1.l_name, t2.l_code, t2.l_name, t1.year_of_birth
from your_table t1
inner join your_table t2
on t1.year_of_birth = t2.year_of_birth
and t1.l_code <> t2.l_code;
```

You might want to keep the l_code column as there can be potentially many users with same name.

NOTE: It'll not produce those users which don't have any other user will the same year_of_birth, but you can fiddle with outer joins to achieve that.